# Jekyll permalink with filename based url

Tags: jekyll, permalinks

I need some help with jekyll permalinks. I've a post named: `DATE-my-title.md`
and inside it I have:

```
---
title: My beautiful extended title
---
```

In `_config.yml` I've defined

```
permalink:   /:categories/:title
```

So it seems that jekyll ignores the filename and instead of getting `/my-title`I'm getting `/my-beautiful-extended-title`

How can I tell jekyll to use the filename url instead of the `title`attribute itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a title in the front matter this is the one used to generate the file name.
If you want to use the file name as generated file name, don't use the front matter title. It's the only way.

Comment: Yep, it seems so :(
What I've done finally is to create a new attribute called 'url' in the front matter, so my permalink will looks like /:categories/:url and I can keep the title attribute to create the <h1> Showing the actual title.

Answer (score 1):

Set the permalink to use `:name` instead

Your `_config.yml`:

```yaml
permalink:   /:categories/:name
```